# Find document where field exist or is null

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
"...": ...
"validated_at": null
"archived_at": null
"..." : ...
}
```

I want to find all documents where `validated_at` is `null` AND `archived_at` is `null` OR doesn't exist in the document

I'm using motor so my query is a bit different but currently I only filter documents where `validated_at` is `null` and `archive_at` doesn't exist:

```
# "$type": 10 is for null bson value
await db.fdeses.find({'validated_at': {"$type": 10}, 'archived_at': {"$exists": False}}).to_list(CURSOR_LIMIT)
```

I tried using `"$or"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: MongoDB Manual [Query for Null or Missing Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/) - there is notes about using with _Motor_.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works perfectly indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following database structure. I have added a field that shows expected query result.

This seems to return what you are looking for.

You can check out [a live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sHDfEgdOCMl) via Mongo Playground.

### Database

```
[
  {
    "validated_at": null,
    "shouldBeReturned": true
  },
  {
    "validated_at": 2,
    "shouldBeReturned": false
  },
  {
    "validated_at": null,
    "archived_at": null,
    "shouldBeReturned": true
  },
  {
    "validated_at": 3,
    "shouldBeReturned": false
  },
  {
    "validated_at": 5,
    "archived_at": null,
    "shouldBeReturned": false
  }
]
```

### Query

```
db.collection.find({
  validated_at: null,
  archived_at: null
})
```

### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "shouldBeReturned": true,
    "validated_at": null
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "archived_at": null,
    "shouldBeReturned": true,
    "validated_at": null
  }
]
```